# SAPUI5 libraries for mobile application

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I just wanted to know which latest SAPUI5 libraries are required for mobile applications out of apf, ca, chart, collaboration, fiori, gantt, landvisz, m, makeit, me, ndc, ovp, portal, suite, tnt, ui, uiext, ushell, uxap, ve and viz.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only require the libraries that you are using with their dependencies.
For an average mobile application, I would say those are `sap.ui.core`, `sap.m`, and maybe `sap.ui.layout`.

There are some supported library combinations, so for example you <s>couldn't</s> shouldn't use `sap.ui.commons` with `sap.m`:
[image: Supported Library Combinations]